# Reusable module in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to get an `autoscaling group name` variable in `module_apps` and use it in other modules - for example `module_init`. However when I try to run `terraform plan` it does not work.

## content of module_apps

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" 
{
  name = "asg-ad"
}

output "asg_name" 
{
  value = "${aws_autoscaling_group.example.name}"
}
```

## content of module_init

```
module "module_init" 
{
  source = "../module_apps"
  asg_name = "${module.module_init.asg_name}"
}
```

Trying to run `terraform plan` seems that it can't get the source module:

```
o:Get: file:///home/user/terraform/application/module_apps
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_init
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_elb
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_deloy
o:Get: file:///home/user/terraform/application/module_apps
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_init
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_elb
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_deloy
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_init
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_elb
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_deloy
o:Get: file:///home/user/terraform/application/module_apps
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_init
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_elb
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_deloy
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_init
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_elb
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_deloy
o:Get: file:///home/user/terraform/application/module_apps
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_init
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_elb
o:Get: file:///home/user//terraform/application/module_deloy
```

Comment: Why did you do a `terraform apply` and not a `terraform init` or `terraform apply`?

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't outright fail you can expect to see a cycle warning where you've created a loop in Terraform and it's trying to fulfil your request for `asg-name` before the asg has been created.

To get what you need you'll need to have something like the following:

## **module_apps/module_apps.tf**

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  name = "${var.asg_name}"
}
```

## **module_init.tf**

```
variable "asg_name" { default = "asg-ad" }

module "module_init" {
  source = "../module_apps"

  asg_name = "${var.asg_name}"
}

output "asg_name" {
  value = "${var.asg_name}"
}
```

This way, if you call `module_init` somewhere else you'll have `asg_name` available to you. Always be careful of trying to use an output of a module to create the module, Terraform doesn't handle loops like that well and the errors can be confusing to diagnose.

Comment: Could you explain what error message indicates this or is there an issue logged somewhere else, e.g. github?

Comment: It's expected behaviour, I've edited the answer with what he can expect to see as an error message.